# All about EscapeJQuerySelector(text).?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know about **EscapeJQuerySelector(text)**. Please elaborate this.
I am using this method to escape the sequences.

JQuery Codes for reference :

```
var a = '.div';
alert(EscapeJQuerySelector(a));
```

The value I got in alert is `/.div` instead of `.div`

I don't want to add anything extra, I just wanted to escape the values. I have to use **EscapeJQuerySelector()** to escape sequences and regular expression.

Is there any way to use `EscapeJQuerySelector()` and it will return me the expected output `".div"` instead of adding extra *"/"*

Comment: What is that `EscapeJQuerySelector()` function you speak of?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi wait, I'll updating it.

Comment: This makes no sense? A quick Google search turns up nothing on this mystical `EscapeJQuerySelector` function, so how are we supposed to answer this ? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I got the answer, Sorry for the trouble guys, How can I delete this post.?